# Windows Phone 8 I Can't add c++ Template to project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, windows-phone-8

Let's describe my problem:

I've created a Windows 8 App already, its written in c++/cli and xaml.
Now I want to get this App to Windows Phone 8. 
So my first step is creating a new project:

[image]

Then I want to add a new element based on a c++ template but VS just shows me c# templates:

[image]

You remember? I created a project based on C++!
**How can I add new elements based on c++ template like I do in normal Windows 8 SDK?:**
[image]

Do I have to download those templates somewhere? Is there any other way to get my Xaml pages based on c++ from windows 8 project to windows phone 8 project?

Comment: This is Microsoft's deliberate misinformation to give impression that c++ apps could be published in Wp8 app store. Look here for further http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173039/is-modern-c-replacing-c-is-microsoft-pushing-developers-to-adopt-c/177048#177048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't support writing C++/XAML applications, only C++/D3D ones. That's why there are no C++/XAML templates. You can mix XAML and D3D but you'd need to write the XAML UI layer in C# or VB.

See [Native code on Windows Phone 8 topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details. To quote:

> Windows Phone 8 doesn’t support the XAML UI with C++ code-behind app model that is supported for Windows Store apps.

Comment: +1. For more information on interoperability between XAML & C# and D3D & C++ see @  http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Native:_Interoperability_between_DirectX_and_C.2B.2B.2C_and_XAML_and_C.23