# visual c++ with html 5 project template not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I downloaded Microsoft visual studio express 2012 for windows phone.
But when I go to new project, I can't find HTML5 app for visual c++ project template.
However HTML5 app for visual c# and visual basic is found.

It seem like microsoft done this on purpose (don't know why).
Does anyone know guide to create new HTML5 app with visual c++ project template?
any link would be useful.

edit: I did more searching and found this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940(v=vs.105).aspx

> HTML-based phone apps aren’t a supported app model in Windows
>   Phone 8. However, a developer can create a managed app with a XAML
>   front end that uses an embedded browser control to display local HTML
>   content,

However this only apply to windows phone 8 and not windows 8
which is the source of confusion for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the HTML app template is a `WebBrowserControl` hosted inside in small XAML/.NET app layer, and it isn't currently possible to write a XAML/C++ app on WP8.

If you need to add C++ you should be able to add a Windows Runtime component to your app and call through to that: although that would mean calling through from JS->.NET->WinRT.

Comment: how about for UI if i discard html 5 but c++ is a must.Does that mean I must go through XAML and .NET(c#/VB.net) for ui and c++ in the backend?The annoying thing is html 5/javascript/C++ works in windows 8 EXCEPT for windows phone 8 which I just discovered today.

Comment: I'm afraid so. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719707/windows-phone-8-i-cant-add-c-template-to-project/13720762#13720762